# Loop over list of names and add Jquery on click listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set it that for every checkbox with the class `country` on check finds every input with `this` attribute name and toggleClass on the div. It's only working on the first input.

```
$(".country").each(function(){
  var country_name = $(this).attr('name');
 if(this.click) {
    $("."+country_name).each(function() {
                $( this ).toggleClass('hide');
            });
}
 });


<div id="country" class="form-group">
    <label>Country</label><br>
    <input class="country" id="Kenya" type="checkbox" value="Kenya" name="Kenya"> Kenya<br>
    <input class="country" id="Uganda" type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="Uganda"> Uganda<br>
    <input class="country" id="Tanzania" type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="Tanzania"> Tanzania<br>
  </div>

  <div id="destination" class="form-group">
    <label>Destination</label><br>
    <div class="Kenya"><input type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="des1"> Maasai Mara<br></div>
    <div class="Kenya"><input type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="des2"> Serengeti<br></div>
    <div class="Kenya"><input type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="des3"> KWS<br></div>

    <div class="Uganda"><input type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="des1"> Maasai Mara<br></div>
    <div class="Uganda"><input type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="des2"> Serengeti<br></div>
    <div class="Uganda"><input type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="des3"> KWS<br></div>

    <div class="Tanzania"><input type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="des1"> Maasai Mara<br></div>
    <div class="Tanzania"><input type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="des2"> Serengeti<br></div>
    <div class="Tanzania"><input type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="des3"> KWS<br></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What do you think that `if (this.click)` is checking for?

Comment: Binding event within loop is absolutely bad process!! Though the binding it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.country').click(function () {
  $('.' + $(this).attr('id')).toggleClass('hide');
  // or $('.' + this.name).toggleClass('hide');
});
```

[http://jsbin.com/sisawe/3/](http://jsbin.com/sisawe/3/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 1):

Do it simply:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"].country').on('click', function (){
    var name = $.trim(this.name);
    $('#destination div.' + name).toggleClass('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would do that

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.country').on('click', function() {
        $('.' + this.name).toggleClass( 'hide' );
    });
});
```

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.country').on('click', function() {
            $('.' + this.name).toggleClass( 'hide' );
        });
    });
```

```css
.hide {
  display:none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="country" class="form-group">
    <label>Country</label><br>
    <input class="country" id="Kenya" type="checkbox" value="Kenya" name="Kenya"> Kenya<br>
    <input class="country" id="Uganda" type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="Uganda"> Uganda<br>
    <input class="country" id="Tanzania" type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="Tanzania"> Tanzania<br>
  </div>

  <div id="destination" class="form-group">
    <label>Destination</label><br>
    <div class="Kenya"><input type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="des1"> Maasai Mara<br></div>
    <div class="Kenya"><input type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="des2"> Serengeti<br></div>
    <div class="Kenya"><input type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="des3"> KWS<br></div>

    <div class="Uganda"><input type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="des1"> Maasai Mara<br></div>
    <div class="Uganda"><input type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="des2"> Serengeti<br></div>
    <div class="Uganda"><input type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="des3"> KWS<br></div>

    <div class="Tanzania"><input type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="des1"> Maasai Mara<br></div>
    <div class="Tanzania"><input type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="des2"> Serengeti<br></div>
    <div class="Tanzania"><input type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="des3"> KWS<br></div>
  </div>
```

But I think this is what you intended:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.country').on('change', function() {
        $('.' + this.name).toggleClass( 'hide', !this.checked );
    })
    .change();
});
```

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.country').on('change', function() {
            $('.' + this.name).toggleClass( 'hide', !this.checked );
        })
        .change();
    });
```

```css
.hide {
  display:none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="country" class="form-group">
    <label>Country</label><br>
    <input class="country" id="Kenya" type="checkbox" value="Kenya" name="Kenya"> Kenya<br>
    <input class="country" id="Uganda" type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="Uganda"> Uganda<br>
    <input class="country" id="Tanzania" type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="Tanzania"> Tanzania<br>
  </div>

  <div id="destination" class="form-group">
    <label>Destination</label><br>
    <div class="Kenya"><input type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="des1"> Maasai Mara<br></div>
    <div class="Kenya"><input type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="des2"> Serengeti<br></div>
    <div class="Kenya"><input type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="des3"> KWS<br></div>

    <div class="Uganda"><input type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="des1"> Maasai Mara<br></div>
    <div class="Uganda"><input type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="des2"> Serengeti<br></div>
    <div class="Uganda"><input type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="des3"> KWS<br></div>

    <div class="Tanzania"><input type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="des1"> Maasai Mara<br></div>
    <div class="Tanzania"><input type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="des2"> Serengeti<br></div>
    <div class="Tanzania"><input type="checkbox" value="xxx" name="des3"> KWS<br></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The event handler can be delegated to the checkbox's containing div, thereby attaching the handler to just one element instead of many.

There's also no need for a 'hide' class (unless it does something other than hide). Use `.hide()` and `.show()` instead.

Verbosely :

```
$("#country").on('change', 'input', function() {
    var country = $(this).attr('name');
    if(this.checked) {
        $("#destination div." + country).show();
    } else {
        $("#destination div." + country).hide();
    }
}).find('input').trigger('change');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4h96s6yd/)**

Or concisely :

```
$("#country").on('change', 'input', function () {
    $("#destination div." + $(this).attr('name'))[['hide', 'show'][+this.checked]]();
}).find('input').trigger('change');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4h96s6yd/1/)**